# Separation (|) in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Taken directly from [CodeIgniter page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
```

This part:

```
'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean'
```

Does PHP have an inbuilt feature to seperate values by | checks, or CodeIgniter does it manually?

If so,

Why don't they use something like this?

```
set_rules('username', 'Username', array('trim', 'required' ...));
```

Isn't it alot easier to deal with arrays instead of wasting unnecessary codes to check | symbol and seperate tags?

Comment: Please give a link actually leading to the text "_directly from CodeIgniter page_". That could give others some insight.

Comment: "Isn't it alot easier to deal with arrays instead of wasting unnecessary codes to check | symbol and seperate tags?" --- codeigniter is not a piece of software you want to learn on. So don't wonder if you see something weird in their code ;-)

Comment: Hi, here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: [http://php.net/explode](http://php.net/explode) then they call functions and add parameters, its syntax is smaller and easier to read than array

Comment: It's syntactically easier on the user to pipe delimit the list than code out arrays. In the end the user is responsible for optimizing their sites so the overhead difference, if any, is not really a concern. Either way this is not a programming issue. I think CI will accept messages from users so maybe you can lobby for them to change in the future, even though everyone that's used the framework knows they won't change that because we all like it.

Comment: Syntax is sure easier to read, but isn't it pretty hard to maintain? Like, if you mess up your array, PHP will give a fatal error, but if you mess up a |, the set_rules function will return true regardless, even if it doesn't sanitize xss itself. 

Ps. I don't use CI really, just saw it in documentation and wanted to ask.

Comment: I prefer the array method of validation myself, and find it easier to read, but then again, I know how to write and read PHP, where as a lot of new coders that use CI might be slightly inexperienced.

Comment: I guess hard to maintain would depend on how you use your own system. Personally, in the many CI projects I have had to work on, the rules on a well planned system rarely change and if they do it's not like this is a huge problem. There are way more things to complain about with CI than this, but I appreciate it none the less.

Answer (score 3):

CodeIgniter will run an `explode()` on that string, using `|` (pipe) as the separator. All it is at the end of the day is the likings and creativity of designers.

Below is the snippet from [CI source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php) which does the splitting.

```
// Cycle through the rules for each field, match the
// corresponding $_POST item and test for errors
    foreach ($this->_field_data as $field => $row)
    {
        // Fetch the data from the corresponding $_POST or validation array and cache it in the _field_data array.
        // Depending on whether the field name is an array or a string will determine where we get it from.
        if ($row['is_array'] === TRUE)
        {
            $this->_field_data[$field]['postdata'] = $this->_reduce_array($validation_array, $row['keys']);
        }
        elseif (isset($validation_array[$field]) && $validation_array[$field] !== '')
        {
            $this->_field_data[$field]['postdata'] = $validation_array[$field];
        }

        // Don't try to validate if we have no rules set
        if (empty($row['rules']))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $this->_execute($row, explode('|', $row['rules']), $this->_field_data[$field]['postdata']);
    }
```

Comment: So, explode() function will work whenever you want to sanitize a variable. Isn't it just unnecessary? explode() will be called few times, causing performance loss, also it is really hard to maintain such code, like once you forget to put a | (like requiredxss_clean) it won't clear xss or make the field required, probably even causing problems in database side. I'm not tying to bash CodeIgniter, haven't really used it before, just didn't saw the usage of | in PHP before so wanted to ask.

Comment: all `explode();` will do is turn a string into an array using a specified character as the separator. It is unnecessary from your point of view, but the FW developers wanted to make it easier for users of their framework. Small things like this are what make one fw more enjoyable vs another one.